# What does 'Type not allowed here' mean?

Tags: swift, mvvm, callback, protocols

I'm using Swift 2.3 and trying to create a callback function that will cause my `UIViewController` to update itself with the updated view model but I'm getting a compile error in my view model class - 'Type not allowed here'. I'm getting other errors as well but they all seem to be cause by a fundamental problem with my `CalculatorViewModel` class. It's worth noting that I'm following an example of MVVM used in this great [post](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52#.bu6fn6v20) about iOS architecture patterns and trying to adapt it to my app.

Here's my view controller:

```
class CalculatorViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, DismissalDelegate {


  var viewModel: CalculatorViewModelProtocol! {
    didSet {
      self.viewModel.oneRepMaxDidChange = { [unowned self] viewModel in
        self.oneRepMaxField.text = String(viewModel.oneRepMax!)
      }
    }
  }

override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()

let viewModel = CalculatorViewModel() // use of unresolved identifier 'CalculatarViewModel'

self.viewModel = viewModel

liftNameButton.setTitle(viewModel.liftName, forState: .Normal)
weightLiftedField.text = String(viewModel.weightLifted)
repetitionsField.text = String(viewModel.repetitions)
units.text = viewModel.units
oneRepMaxField.text = String(viewModel.oneRepMax!)

// a bunch of formatting code and then I add a target to a button the user will press:

calculateButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onCalculateTapped), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

func onCalculateButtonTapped() {
if let weightLifted = weightLiftedField.text, let repetitions = repetitionsField.text {

// error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments (except that it does)
viewModel!.calculateOneRepMax(weightLifted, repetitions: repetitions)
  //weightPercentages = getPercentages(pureOneRepMax!)
} else {
  return
}
```

and here's my view model and a view model protocol where the 'Type not allowed error' appears:

```
protocol CalculatorViewModelProtocol: class {
    var liftName: String? { get }
    var weightLifted: Double? { get }
    var repetitions: Int? { get }
    var oneRepMax: String? { get set }
    var oneRepMaxDidChange: ((CalculatorViewModelProtocol) -> ())? { get set }
    var units: String? { get }
    var date: String? { get }
    func calculateOneRepMax()

**// the 'Type not allowed here' error is here**
class CalculatorViewViewModel:  CalculatorViewModelProtocol, LiftEventDataManagerDelegate {      

    let calculator = CalculatorBrain()
    private let dataManager = LiftEventDataManager()

    var liftName: String?
    var weightLifted: String!
    var repetitions: String!
    var oneRepMax: String? {
        didSet {
            self.oneRepMaxDidChange?(self)
        }
    }
    var units: String?
    var date: String?

    var oneRepMaxDidChange: ((CalculatorViewModelProtocol) -> ())?

    @objc func calculateOneRepMax(weightLifted: String, repetitions: String) {
        let result = calculator.calculateOneRepMax(Double(weightLifted)!, repetitions: UInt8(repetitions)!)
    }

init() {

    dataManager.requestData(withViewModel: self)
  }   
}
```

I've done a lot of searching but haven't found any answers that help.

Comment: You are trying to declare a class (`CalculatorViewViewModel`) inside a protocol. Don't do that.

Comment: Your code is weird. If I synthesize it : `protocol P : class { class A }` What is it supposed to mean ? I think you should remove the " : class" and close your brace before your "class Calculator..."

Comment: Your comments caused me to focus more on that protocol definition and it turns out I had accidentally deleted the closing '}' which messed everything up. I've fixed that and now I'm it's complaining that my class isn't conforming to the protocol but I think I know how to deal with that. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can not implement a class inside a protocol. Move your  CalculatorViewModel to a separate file or at least outside the scope of the protocol